# Site não exibe CSS após Publicação

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

Após publicar meu site, o css não carrega em toda a página, ficando apenas em HTML. Estou usando Bootsrap Less.

Minha estrutura:

[image: Content]

Bundle:

```html
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace WebAutenticado
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/css/site.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Se utiliza o Google Chrome, aperte F12, vá em **Console** e veja se você está recebendo algum erro **404**.

Comment: Estou (403), como resolver isso?

Comment: Você poderia colocar uma foto desse erro?

Comment: O arquivo existe mas não possuí permissão de acesso, então o servidor se recusa a carrega-lo junto com o site. Esse problema provavelmente está vindo do seu host, entre em contato com a equipe ou procure no site deles algum tutorial de como resolver este problema. Um exemplo do que eu estou falando é essa página aqui: http://www.redehost.com.br/duvidas/erro-403-permisso-negada-como-resolver--1611

Comment: Erro de Permissão, OK, resolvido dentro do servidor.

Comment: Ótimo Marcos, que bom que resolveu :)